# Creating a dictionary from csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am new at this and have been reading many articles but can't figure this out. I'm trying to create a dictionary from this tsv file:

```
fname   lname   marks
Alice   Brown   8.5
Francine    Walters 9
Robert  Wilson  7
Evelyn  Stewart 10
Margo   Kazinsky    9.5
Gordon  Rogers  8.5
Stephanie   Hoover  9
Roger   Brosnan 8.7
Francine    Williamson  9
Leonard Runka   8
Rosalind    Samuelson   6.5
Sasha   Levchenko   8
Anastasia   Melnyk  8.5
Charlie Watson  8
```

I don't know how to make them into a dictionary and return the name of the student with the highest grade. This is what I've tried so far:

```
import csv

f = open('grades.tsv')
grades= []
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
for line in csv_f:
    print(line[0])
    grades.append(line[0])

f.close()

print(sorted(grades[2]))
print(len(grades))
print(grades)
print(type(line[0]))
print(grades.strip('\t'))
```

Comment: Well, for starters you don't have a step that involves dicts in any way. Maybe...try that.

Comment: look into `csv.DictReader` in `csv` module and your delimiter may be "\t" if its tsv.

Comment: The parameter `delimiter = ','` is wrong — your values are separated by tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I think it would be a little easier to use `csv.DictReader`:

```
import csv

grades = {}
with open('grades.tsv', newline='') as csv_f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csv_f, delimiter='\t'):
        fullname = row['fname'] + ' ' + row['lname']
        grades[fullname] = float(row['marks'])

print(grades)
```

Output:

```
{'Sasha Levchenko': 8.0, 'Charlie Watson': 8.0, 'Marie Curie': 10.0,
 'Margo Kazinsky': 9.5, 'Alice Brown': 8.5, 'Stephanie Hoover': 9.0,
 'Rosalind Samuelson': 6.5, 'Gordon Rogers': 8.5, 'Anastasia Melnyk': 8.5,
 'Evelyn Stewart': 10.0, 'Francine Walters': 9.0, 'Leonard Runka': 8.0,
 'Robert Wilson': 7.0, 'Roger Brosnan': 8.7, 'Francine Williamson': 9.0}
```

Finding the student with the highest grade is a little trickier, since there can be more than one if there's a tie. Here's how to that can be handled (note: for testing purposes I added another student row to the file):

```
Marie   Curie   10
```

And the following lines of code:

```
highest_grade = max(grades.values())
print('highest_grade: {}'.format(highest_grade))
tie = list(grades.values()).count(highest_grade) > 1
print('student{} with highest grade:'.format('s' if tie else ''))
for student, grade in sorted(grades.items(), key=
                             lambda s: s[0].split()[::-1]): # Sort by lname
    if grade == highest_grade:
        print('  ', student)
```

To get the following output:

```
highest_grade: 10.0
students with highest grade:
   Marie Curie
   Evelyn Stewart
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to be the **key** in the dictionary you desire to build?  You don't make it very clear.  Assuming it's the `firstname, lastname` 2-items tuple, for example:

```
with open('grades.tsv') as f:
    # assuming the first row is "headers", let's skip it
    next(f)
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    d = dict(((first, last), float(grade))
             for first, last, grade in r)
```

You will, of course, need to ensure the right delimiter: "tsv" seems to imply the delimiter is a tab, and so does the look of the data you show, but you've explicitly forced it to a comma (I'm using tab in this example, but, make sure you take a look at the file's contents and pick the right one).

Also, based on a comment to this answer from the OP (and the data shown in the Q), it seems the first row of the file may be just headers, not data; so, I've added the `next(f)` to skip it (remove it if the file's actually all made up of actual data, no header line).

Now `d` is the dict you seek.  To look for the student with the highest grade, e.g:

```
top_student = max(d, key=d.get)
print(' '.join(top_student))
```

Comment: I have tried your method, but I get: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'marks'. ...?

Comment: @liya77: You probably need to skip the first row of the file which has the column/fieldnames it it. Just add a `r.next()` statement right after the `r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')`.

Comment: Right @martineau , thanks for spotting this -- editing to note the fact.

Comment: @martineau, I tried and it says "AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'" but then I put "next(f)" and it worked! Thank you though

Comment: `next(r)` would work just as well as `next(f)` -- but the name of the method the `next` built-in invokes depends on your Python version, used to be `.next` but later became `.__next__`.  Best not to worry about it and use the `next(...)` built-in function.